# Returning pointers that point to member data

Tags: c++

Pseudocode, I don't know if this compiles or not, but you get the idea.

```
class DataHolder
{
    void GetData(float* ptr)
    {
        ptr = dataNeededByOtherClass;
    }

    float* dataNeededByOtherClass; // Initialized and modified elsewhere
};

class DataUser
{
    void DoStuff()
    {
         float* ptrToData;
         dataHolder->GetData(ptrToData);

         // ptrToData points to garbage Why?

         ptrToData = dataHolder->dataNeededByOtherClass;
         // ptrToData now points to the correct data
    }
};
```

What am I looking at here?

Comment: A) "I don't know if this compiles", why havent you tried compiling it? B) pointers are passed by value, which means GetData() does nothing (its modifying the local parameter). Why dont you just return `dataNeededByOtherClass` from GetData() instead?

Comment: The data is an array of some size. I also need to return the size separately.

Comment: I don't see how that keeps you from doing `float* GetData() { return dataNeededByOtherClass; }`. Which would be clearer.

Comment: off topic but I need: void GetData(float** data, int** size);

Comment: No, what you really need is `std::vector<float>& GetData();` but that's just my opinion. (P.S: it would be `int*` not `int**` as the size is not an array but a straight integer).

Answer (score 5):

The function

```
void GetData(float* ptr)
```

receives the pointer argument by value. Modifying `ptr` within the function does not change the value of `ptrToData`. Instead, try to pass a pointer by pointer:

```
void GetData(float** ptrptr)
{
    *ptrptr = dataNeededByOtherClass;
}

float* ptrToData;
dataHolder->GetData(&ptr);
```

---

**P.S.** Please note that exposing class variables in such a way is not considered as best practice.

Comment: Although a reference argument is (arguably) preferable to a pointer; and returning a value by value is (unarguably) better than either.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yes. In the real world, my preferences would be: (a) do not do it or implement `const float * GetData() const`; (b) implement `float* GetData() const`; (c) use a reference. But for the sake of this exercise, I guess `**ptrptr` is more straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

Hi there are several syntax errors in your code. The code below doesn't add constructors and destructors as you mention them in your text above. Your data needs to come from somewhere :) I took the libery of creating a SetData method below. Note that I also free the memory of your buffer in both the destructor and when you set the pointer, if the pointer is not null. If you don't want this just cut it away :)

**Working Code**

```
class DataHolder
{
private:
    float* dataNeededByOtherClass; // Initialized and modified elsewhere
public:
    float* GetData()
    {
        return dataNeededByOtherClass;
    }

    void SetData(float* ptr)
    {
        // Remove if you intend to keep this memory and release it elsewhere
        if (dataNeededByOtherClass != NULL)
            delete[] dataNeededByOtherClass;

        dataNeededByOtherClass = ptr;
    }   

    // You are missing constructors and destructors
    DataHolder() : dataNeededByOtherClass(NULL){};
    DataHolder(float *ptr) : dataNeededByOtherClass(ptr){};
    ~DataHolder()
    {
        // if you want to release data after class is destructed.. if not remove these lines
        if (dataNeededByOtherClass != NULL)
            delete[] dataNeededByOtherClass;
    };
}

class DataUser
{
    void DoStuff()
    {
        DataHolder dataHolder; // either feed data in c'tor or use dataHolder->SetData() for filling data, now it's just empty.. 
        float* ptrToData = dataHolder.GetData();
    }
};
```

Hope it helps.